# Why is Jaxb2 pluggin (Java11) failing to generate base class - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, xml-parsing, jaxb, java-11, xsd-validation

It is a clean project and i have a simple xsd to generate its classes. Everything goes right till i try to set a tns type, then parse error apperars: (Unable to parse input schema(s))

```
xs:element name="cufdRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="codeBehaviour" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="codeSystem" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="codeMode" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="codePlace" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="codePos" type="xs:int" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="cufdRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="cufdCode" type="tns:cufdCode" />              
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  
    <xs:complexType name="cufdCode">            
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" />                         
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

Here my pluggin config

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                                <id>xmls</id>
                                <goals>
                                        <goal>generate</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                        <generateDirectory>target/generated-sources/xjc/</generateDirectory>
                                        <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/</schemaDirectory>
                                        <schemaIncludes>
                                                <include>**/*.xsd</include>
                                        </schemaIncludes>
                                        <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schemas/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                                        <bindingIncludes>
                                                <include>**/*.xjb</include>
                                        </bindingIncludes>
                                </configuration>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
                                <version>2.3.3</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3</version>
                </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

To remark, classes has been generated while i don't use a reference to another complex type

Answer (score 0):

The problem was generated form tns definition on the header of xml, or any format of the tags. Solution is not clear to me yet, but problem is not pluggin. That pom config is working, if you were looking for a correct call for Java 11 onward